# SQL Server: how to change data entry from VARCHAR to DATETIME?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below sample data:

`03202012` as date but the column datatype is `Varchar`.

I want to convert it to `2012-03-20 00:00:00.000` as `Datetime`.

I tried using

```
CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), Column, 101) AS DATETIME)
```

But I get an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Complete code snippet to test:

```
DECLARE @Column VARCHAR(MAX) = '03202012'

SELECT CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), @Column, 101) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: If you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer, I'd recommend to use `DATE` (if you need the date only - no time portion) or then `DATETIME2(n)` for date & time instead of `DATETIME` (which has a number of annoying issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found below script help me solved my concern.

```
SELECT convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF('31012016',3,0,'-'),6,0,'-'), 105)

Result: 2016-01-31 00:00:00.000
```

Thanks all for the effort. :D

Comment: Is it okay to ask the question and post the answer by same person. I have never seen in SO @Ajay2707

Comment: There is no issue with that, only want to close the question by accepting any one answer.

Comment: @Ajay2707, how can i do that to close this question?

Comment: in each answer, below the down arrow there is right sign, click on it.

Comment: there's a label stating: You can accept your own answer in 2 days.

Comment: Substring() approach use the ODBC canonical format which is more reliable. I have seen, putting dashes may cause trouble, try in all versions and language, dateformat settings before putting it into use. This was discussed somewhere. Better is not to use any dashes IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Use yyyyMMdd format, that always works:

```
DECLARE @myDateString varchar(10) = '03202012';
SELECT cast( substring(@myDateString, 5, 4)+
             substring(@myDateString, 1, 2)+
             substring(@myDateString, 3, 2) AS datetime);
```

Comment: I would be inclined to use `left()` and `right()`, but this is the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use the `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert a string to a date. For your example, it would look like this

```
STR_TO_DATE("03-02-2012", "%m-%d-%Y");
```

Note that the format part of the string must match the format part of the date.

Edit: Just found out this is for SQL Server, but I assume this will work there as well.

Comment: NO, it will not. Question is tagged with `SQL Server` and in such case no point in giving a MySQL specific answer. Isn't it?